# Why can't I declare more than one variable in a for loop's initial statement?

Tags: c, cs50

When using a with one variable, we declare it to 0 as i=0 like here

but when we use two variables as if I add n = strlen to make the code more efficient then i=0 is not declared but a comma is used and n=strlen(s) is declared. Why can't we use 'i=0;' here as done in the previous code?

Edit: The cs50.h is part of the sandbox cs50 which is made by harvard.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    string s = get_string("Input:  ");
    printf("Output: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++)
    {
        printf("%c\n", s[i]);
    }
}
```

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    string s = get_string("Input: ");
    printf("Output:\n");
    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(s); i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%c\n", s[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Why can't we use 'i=0;' here as done in the previous code? ` - there is `int i = 0` in both code snippets you attached. How would you want to use `i = 0`? `i=0 is not declared` - No, it's still declared.

Comment: You can declare more than one variable. Both code samples here are fine.

Comment: @KamilCuk In the first code, we used i=0; but in the second one we used i=0, as here we used a comma and didn't declare it. When I try to use "i=0;" in the second code, a error pops up saying --use of undeclared identifier 'n'-- even though I used "n=strlen(s);"

Comment: @interjay Yes both are fine but my question is why can't we use "i=0;" in the second one.

Comment: No, with a comma it's still a declaration. `int i = 0, n = strlen(s);` and `int i = 0;` both declare a variable `i` and initialize it to `0`.

Comment: @animesh There really isn't any reason to think that your preferred version is 'more efficient'. To you, it looks like a more efficient use of space, but it is very difficult to guess, especially without a lot of experience, what the compiler will turn that into. And it is best to avoid making a habit of such thinking because code should be readable to humans first and foremost.

Comment: @KamilCuk so I can put multiple variables seperated by a comma but the last one has to be with a semicolon ?

Comment: Because `;` separates the 3 clauses of the `for` loop, so you can't use it between declarations.

Comment: The `;` separates like "sentences". You can do use a comma to separate multiple variable declaration. The `int a = 1, b, c, d, e = a, f = 1 + 5;` is "equivalent" to `int a = 1; int b; int c; int d; int e = a; int f = 1 + 5;`

Comment: @dandan78 it's less efficient as the compiler has to check the string after printing each letter but when I used n=strlen. It makes the compiler more efficient as it rather than checking again and again, the value is stored in n.

Comment: Actually, I've just noticed that I *can* do this! For years, my MSVC compiler complained - maybe they finally updated the base `C` standard? OP- What compiler are you using?

Comment: @AdrianMole Using the sandbox cs50 compiler. It displays a error message-- use of undeclared identifier 'n'--. It uses the C99 version, maybe the newer version is better.

Comment: @AnimeshSingh The compiler isn't dumb. It is perfectly capable of figuring out that the value you are checking against is a constant, especially if the cstring isn't changing in the loop itself... like I said, don't make assumptions based on inadequate knowledge. And even if your assumption were valid, there is nothing preventing you from making the assignment on the line right before your `for` loop.

Comment: @dandan78 They told it was a good practice in the course. I don't really know anything beyond it

Comment: OT: It should be `size_t i = 0, n = strlen(s);` as `strlen()` returns `size_t` not `int`.

Comment: "They told it was a good practice in the course" --> All courses consider what they suggest  is _good practice_ - even when it is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From C standard **ISO/IEC 9899:TC3** / **ISO/IEC 9899/C11**, the grammar description of the `for` statement, **§(6.8.5) iteration-statement**, have 2 different forms:

> `for ( expression_opt ; expression_opt ; expression_opt ) statement`
>
> `for (declaration expression_opt ; expression_opt ) statement`

Note that in the first form we have an expression in the first position, although it is optional as all 3 fields, and all the 3 parts of the statement form are separated by a `;` semicolon used as a delimiter.

In the second form we can see that the first element in parenthesis is a declaration instead of an expression, and we can note also that **there is no semicolon delimiting it**. This is because the **declaration itself is always terminated by a semicolon**.

Paragraph **(6.7) declaration** describe grammar for a **declaration**:

> `declaration-specifiers init-declarator-list_opt ;`

As you can see a `declaration` is always terminated by a semicolon.

A declaration can assume of course the form of multiple declarations initialized as in your:

```
for (int i = 0, n = strlen(s); i < n; i++)
{
    printf("%c\n", s[i]);
}
```

So **you are using the second form where the semicolon delimits the declaration (not the first part of the `for`)**.

Using multiple semicolon is simply a grammar error.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if I understand the question (although I like it).  Both your code snippets work, don't they? Note that we don't know what is in `cs50.h`, but I tried compiling this, and it worked (both compiling and running).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
  char *s = "Hello world!";
  printf("Output:\n");
  for (int i = 0, n = strlen(s); i < n; i++) {
    printf("%c\n", s[i]);
  }
}
```

Two things might be relevant here;
- how `for` works and 
- how variable declaration/initialization works.

You can think about `for` like this:
`for(AAA; BBB; CCC) DDD;`
is the same as

```
{ // Important!
  AAA;
  while(BBB) {
    {
      DDD;
    }
    CCC;
  }
} // Important!
```

The `// Important!` braces are important because the for introduces a new scope, i.e. `i` and `n` won't accessible outside/after the `for` loop.

The other thing is declaration/initialization. So the

```
int i = 0, n = strlen(s);
```

is an initialization of two variables: `i`, `n`. I'm not 100% sure about the proper vocabulary and rules (you can consult the standard), but the idea is that a declaration looks like:
`TYPE VAR1, VAR2, ..., VARn` 
where the `VARx` is a variable name declared, or an "assignment" in which case it is an initialization.

**UPDATE/PART2:**
Usually how I would do this is something like:

```
const int len = strlen(s);
// Good practice to declare const what every you know wont change
for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  // whatever
}
```

But, what if the confusing coma/semicolon could be made consistent and since the semicolon is a *must* let's try to make everything a semicolon, I've tried this:

```
for ({int i = 0; int n = strlen(s); }; i < n; i++) {
  // what ever
}
```

This did not compile, but it also didn't make sense, since if this would have "worked" (in the sense I thought I could but actually couldn't), `i` and `n` would be declared in the small block and it wouldn't be accessible anywhere else, i.e. in `i < n` would not be accessible. So to make them accessible we could try this:

```
int i, n;
for ({i = 0; n = strlen(s); }; i < n; i++) {
  printf("%c\n", s[i]);
}
```

Now this should have worked if the `for`-`while` equivalency stated above would be 100% true, but it's not since apparently the the `AAA` has to be a single statement (usually a declaration) and it can't be a block i.e. `{...}`. Exact compiler error:

```
cc     hola.c   -o hola
hola.c: In function ‘main’:
hola.c:8:8: error: expected expression before ‘{’ token
    8 |   for ({
      |        ^
make: *** [<builtin>: hola] Error 1
```

but as you can see it is already very ugly and all... so yes, you need to use `,` to separate the declarations/initializations and a `;` to terminate it.

Comment: So a comma is used when declaring multiple variables and the last one has the be end with a semicolon. The cs50.h is a header file of a sandbox cs50 made by harvard. It does not really affect anything in for loop. Anyways I got my answer. Thanks

Comment: Adrian Mole where? in the `for` or in the `while`? I think this sort of works! I've tried something else (I will update the answer in a sec), since you might not need it if it is a single statement.

Comment: Animesh Singh basically yes. So your smallest "unit" in your program is a statement, which has to be separated by putting a semicolon at the end. But one declaration statement can have multiple variables declared, and they are separated by commas (and one statement separation semicolon at the end).

Comment: @Emil I would suggest adding `{ DDD; }` in your `while` example. Because user could declare an `int d` in the loop's body, but this will *not* be accessible in the `for` loop's `CCC` clause.

Comment: Was concentrating on the whole answer... but you are right I guess. Will update accordingly.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica You mean a `continue` instead of a break? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @EmilVatai For future reference, the proper response to a question you don't understand correctly is either to vote to close as unclear, or to leave a comment to that effect or both. An answer that includes a disclaimer is not a good choice.

Comment: EmilVatai : removing my previous comment.  Yes a `continue` is not quite the same.

Comment: @dandan78 I disagree. I can remove the disclaimer (as you call it) about _my uncertainty_ since I agree that it is irrelevant to the answer. I think I can never or very rarely understand 100% what another soul thinks, I never considered the question to be unclear (OP certainly put effort into it), hence not voting to close it. And the answer I gave would not have fit into a comment and I think/hope OP benefited from the answer since OP stated to be a novice. But thank you for the reminder.

Comment: @EmilVatai Helping the OP is secondary to creating resources for future visitors. I didn't mean posting your answer as a comment, but requesting clarification. Whether or not OP is a novice is also irrelevant, as _all_ posters should be held to the same standards.